# Query optimization - needs to know a better way to write it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new in query writing and have written a query which look like

```
SELECT *
FROM Pages P
INNER JOIN PageTypes PT ON PT.ID = P.pagetypes_id
INNER JOIN Paragraphs Para ON Para.page_id = P.id

WHERE PT.mame = 'News'
AND Para.layout_id = (SELECT ID FROM Layout_Scripts WHERE  name = 'intro')
```

It seems to work, but I am not sure if it's a good way to write such a query or there are other ways to write an optiomized query

Comment: Avoid using `SELECT *`; specify only those columns you need returned.  Performance also depends on the available indexes.

Comment: You could try a third `INNER JOIN` instead of the second `WHERE`,using the same criteria

Comment: Do you have any issues with performance? Or it is a theoretical question? SQL Server is good enough in building execution plans for such queries without any extra optimization.

Answer (score -1):

i think, this is better

```
DECLARE @ID int

SELECT ID into @ID FROM Layout_Scripts WHERE  name = 'intro'

SELECT *
FROM Pages P
INNER JOIN PageTypes PT ON PT.ID = P.pagetypes_id
INNER JOIN Paragraphs Para ON Para.page_id = P.id
WHERE PT.mame = 'News'
AND Para.layout_id = @ID
```

because if you write in the where, it executes the query for each row
but i think the ID is only 1, and is better if you put it in a variable